# How to subscribe a callback for an Atlas camera

Tags: gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Good Evening.

The problem is my camera handlers don't work when I'm trying to run Atlas in server mode. Another handlers work.

I'm trying to subscribe to Atlas sensors: */multisense_sl/camera/left/image_raw, /multisense_sl/camera/left/camera_info, /multisense_sl/joint_states* like following:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/JointState.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/Image.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


void cb_joints(const sensor_msgs::JointState::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    std::cout << "joint state message: " << msg->position[0] <<
        std::endl;
}

void cb_left_camera(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    std::cout << "laft camera image has been received" << std::endl;
}

void cb_left_camera_info(const sensor_msgs::CameraInfo::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    std::cout << "laft camera info has been received" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "get_line");

    ros::NodeHandle     node;
    ros::Subscriber sb_joints =
        node.subscribe("/multisense_sl/joint_states", 1, cb_joints);

    ros::Subscriber sb_left_camera =
        node.subscribe("/multisense_sl/camera/left/image_raw", 1, cb_left_camera);

    ros::Subscriber sb_left_camera_info =
        node.subscribe("/multisense_sl/camera/left/camera_info", 1, cb_left_camera_info);


    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

So, handler 'joints' works well, but another handlers don't.
I'm running Atlas without GUI (I'm working remotely) as following:

```
roslaunch atlas_utils atlas.launch gzname:=gzserver
```

and I see the following messages:

```
Warning [parser_urdf.cc:1158] urdf2gazebo: link[left_camera_optical_frame] has no inertia, parent joint [left_camera_optical_frame_joint] ignored
.Warning [parser_urdf.cc:1163] urdf2gazebo: link[left_camera_optical_frame] has no inertia, not modeled in gazebo
Warning [parser_urdf.cc:1158] urdf2gazebo: link[right_camera_optical_frame] has no inertia, parent joint [right_camera_optical_frame_joint] ignored
.Warning [parser_urdf.cc:1163] urdf2gazebo: link[right_camera_optical_frame] has no inertia, not modeled in gazebo
Warning [parser.cc:361] Converting a deprecated SDF source[urdf file].
Warning [Converter.cc:60]   Version[1.3] to Version[1.4]
  Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
    $ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
Warning [parser.cc:286] parse from urdf file [/usr/share/drcsim-2.4/gazebo_models/atlas_description/atlas/atlas.urdf].

Error [RenderEngine.cc:608] Can't open display:
Warning [RenderEngine.cc:87] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled
Error [MultiCameraSensor.cc:81] Unable to create MultiCameraSensor. Rendering is disabled.

[ WARN] [1366988210.198860577, 0.817000000]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/left/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1366988210.199127789, 0.818000000]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/left/camera_info' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1366988210.199276765, 0.818000000]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/right/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1366988210.199400927, 0.818000000]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/right/camera_info' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1366988270.197381765, 59.084000000]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/left/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1366988270.197488414, 59.084000000]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/left/camera_info' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1366988270.197523358, 59.084000000]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/right/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1366988270.197571176, 59.084000000]: The input topic '/multisense_sl/camera/right/camera_info' is not yet advertised
```

I guess, cameras can't work in server mode (without starting GUI). Am I right? What is the simplest solution of my problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2572/how-to-subscribe-a-callback-for-an-atlas-camera/) by [msurov](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/327/msurov/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This message indicates the problem:

```
Error [RenderEngine.cc:608] Can't open display:
Warning [RenderEngine.cc:87] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled
```

If a display can't be opened, then camera (and in some cases laser) sensor generation can't be done.  Possible causes:

- X isn't running.
- Nobody is logged into X
- The `DISPLAY` environment variable isn't set correctly; it should usually be set to something like `localhost:0`.
- The user you're running as doesn't have permission to access the X display.

If you're trying to run `gzserver` remotely on a headless machine, you might find my answer to [this related question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2153/drcsim-cant-figure-out-how-to-run-gazebo-on-remote/) useful.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0